# FluentNhibernate - Tried to add many-to-one 'Document' when already added

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm not getting my mapping code, always presenting the same error:
when I boot up the application to create the tables it displays the following error

> Tried to add many-to-one 'Document' when already added.

The is my code:

```
   public class DocTypes
        {
            public virtual Int16 Id { get; private set; }
            public virtual IList<Documents> Documents { get; set; }        
        }


   public class Documents
        {
            public virtual Int64 Id { get; private set; }
            public virtual DocTypes DocType { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<Files> Files { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<Fields> Fields { get; set; }               
        }
 public class Fields
    {

        public virtual Int32 Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual Documents Document { get; set; }    
    }
```

My mappings:

```
public DocTypeMap()
        {
            Table("TbDocType");
            Id(x => x.Id)
               .Column("Num_Id");            
            HasMany(x => x.Documents)
               .KeyColumn("Num_DocType_Id")
               .Inverse()
               .Cascade.All();
            References(x => x.Cabinet, "Num_Cabinets_Id").Cascade.None();
        }
 public DocumentsMap()
        {
            Table("TbDocuments");
            Id(x => x.Id)
             .Column("Num_Id");

            HasMany(x => x.Files)
             .KeyColumn("Num_Document_Id")
             .Inverse()
             .Cascade.All();
            HasMany(x => x.Fields)
             .KeyColumn("Num_Document_Id")
             .Inverse()
             .KeyNullable()
             .Cascade.All();
            References(x => x.DocType, "Num_DocType_Id").Cascade.None();

        }

   public FieldsMap()
        {
            Table("TbFields");
            Id(x => x.Id)
                .Column("Num_Id");
            References(x => x.Document, "Num_Document_Id")
                .Cascade.None();
            References(x => x.Document, "Num_BarCode_Id")
                .Cascade.None();
        }
```

Where is the error?

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be referencing `Document` twice in your `FieldsMap`. Here:

```
References(x => x.Document, "Num_Document_Id")
    .Cascade.None();
References(x => x.Document, "Num_BarCode_Id")
    .Cascade.None();
```

Comment: Sure it was. I could not see, I'm that much time developing my brain is shutting down. Thanks